# how to check if all script in the list meet the boolean condition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[Script used to check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBSDu.png)
[script want to check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3I6o.png)

Hello there! I need some help
Question is simple .. How to check if all the scripts on the list "watch image 1" #same scripts having bool "IsColorMatched" = true then do this and that ??

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < scriptHolderetc.Length; i++)
{
    if (scriptHolderetc[i].IsColorMatched == true )
    {
        // Do this
    }
    else
    {
        // Do That
    }
}
```

But its not working its only check 1 From the list not all scripts .. Foreach method is also not working like this

```cs
Foreach (MainScriptname colors in scriptHolderetc)
{
    if (colors.IsColorMatched == true )
    {
        // Do this
    }
    else
    {
        // Do That
    }
}
```

Just tell me how to check Boolean statement of all scripts and if the condition meets " = true" .. Default all scripts Bool statement is = false then in game im making them  = true .. want to know when all scripts having same bool statement become true . Thank you in advance

Comment: You need two equal signs instead of one : if (colors.IsColorMatched == true )

Comment: no its not working bro .. only 1 script is effective not all on the list

Comment: `if (scriptHolderetc.All(script => script.IsColorMatched)) { do this} else { do that }`

Comment: @Charlieface as just going to say that ^^ So here is just the according API ;)  https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all

Comment: if you dont want to use linq, do a loop and set it to true and if any of them dont meet, set it to false do not do something on meets..

Comment: Could you please reduce tag spamming? What has `android` to do with the question? `unityscript` is deprecated for years now, it should not be used. `boolean-expression` is only relevant if the issue is the expression itself, not simple logic. The only tag that is relevant here is probably `c#` and maybe `unity-game-engine` only for context.

Comment: Thank you very much .. That's perfect .. That's exactly what i want to know .. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You need to check all the scripts first, then call what you want

```
bool passedAllTests = true;
for (int i = 0; i < scriptHolderetc.Length; i++)
{
    if (scriptHolderetc[i].IsColorMatched == false )
    {
        passedAllTests = false; // failed one test
    }
}
if (passedAllTests)
{
// Do this 
}
else
{
// Do That
}
```

Comment: as was already mentioned in the comments this can be done in a single line `if (scriptHolderetc.All(script => script.IsColorMatched)) { do this} else { do that }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try also use `ForEach` method over collections to do some changes on each object

```
           list.ForEach(x =>
           {
               if (x.IsColorMatched)
               {
                   x.Num += 1;
                   //or call other methods
                   DoSomething(x);
               }
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  "Charlieface"
this is working for me as he told

```
        if (paintColors.All(colors => colors.isColormatched))
        {
            Debug.Log("All Color Matched");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("All Color not Matched Yet");
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Loop is not required. The extension method `All` does this loop internally. You are not even using the loop variable `colors`. The `colors` parameter in the lambda expression is another variable with a scope limited to the lambda expression.

Comment: Ok .. Understand .. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq //Important! This is what gives us the .All method.
        
if(scriptHolderetc.All(s => s.IsColorMatched))
{
    //All scripts meet the condition
}
else
{
    //Not all scripts meet the condition
}
```

What this does is check if the specified conditions, `s.IsColorMatched` is true for every element in the array.

`.All`, coming from the `System.Linq` package (comes preinstalled, you just have to import it), returns true if the condition we passed as an argument is true for all elements in the array (.All).

Let's break that a bit more, since the parameter for `.All` can be tricky.

```
s => s.IsColorMatched
```

This is a parameter of type `Func`. `Func`s are anonymous functions (unnamed functions that can be used like variables) that have a return value (in this case, a boolean). For reference, `Action` is the type for anonymous functions that return void. The s before the `=>` specifies that name for our `Func`'s one parameter. Then, the `=>` specifies that this is an anonymous function. Finally, the portion afterwards, the `s.IsColorMatched` specifies what value we're returning. To summarize, we're creating an anonymous function with one parameter called `s` and return `s.IsColorMatched`.

So, what will happen is we'll use `.All` to check if every element's `IsColorMatched` is true and then use that our conditional.

Thanks to @Olivier Jacot-Descombes for mentioning .All elsewhere.